# MySQL failed to start on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm following the OpenStack install tutorial. Get to here: https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-sql-database-ubuntu.html

```
apt install mariadb-server python-pymysql
sudo touch /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/99-openstack.cnf

# Put this in above file...
[mysqld]
bind-address = 10.0.0.11

default-storage-engine = innodb
innodb_file_per_table = on
max_connections = 4096
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

I've created the `.cnf` file and now `sudo service mysql restart` fails.

I delete the `.cnf` and it starts.

Nothing useful in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: Try /var/log/error.log instead.

Comment: @chrispeckham Please post complete content of both error logs.  We may see something that is important to analyze.

Comment: Look for `mysqld.err`, not `error.log`.